# Using a TdwsUnit implicitly

Tags: delphi, dwscript

Is assigning the TDelphiWebScript object to the TdwsUnit's Script property sufficient to use it implicitly? (Without having to add it to uses in the script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is sufficient, unless you enable the coExplicitUnitUses compiler option, in which case the scripts need to "uses" everything (except the Internal unit).

For simple scripting usage, the implicit use works well, for complex projects with lots (or large) TdwsUnit, having explicit uses can be used to reduce compile times or give better control about what is in scope.